# Optimal clusterization

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, graph-algorithm

There is a graph (E,V). For each edge (i,j), there is a payment P[i,j] which may be positive, zero, or negative.  We divide the vertices by clusters.  Each time two neighbour vertices v1 and v2 belong to the different clusters, we receive the payment P[v1,v2].  How to maximize the total payment?  Is this problem NP-hard?

Comment: You are looking for a [multi-cut](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~anupamg/adv-approx/lecture18.pdf).

Comment: If there are no further restrictions (e.g. the number of resulted cluster must by a given M), what's stopping me to iterate over the edges and cut all with positive payments? True, it may result in a still contiguous graph (no partitioning) but, as the problem doesn't impose any restriction, a single cluster as result is acceptable, isn't it?

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi We cannot arbitrary cut some edges and not cut others.  We can only cut edges from different clusters.  If we cut A-B, but don't cut B-C, we shoud cut A-C too.

Comment: "We cannot arbitrary cut some edges and not cut others." Where's the explanation for those restriction?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi - in the text of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for clustering, but for *cuts*.

Maximizing the weight of edges cut is commonly called a "maximum cut". The more common problem is the minimum cut, and there are some clustering algorithms expressed in terms of the mincut problem. Cuts are also related to flow networks.

As noted in the comments, you will need to specify some boundary conditions. For example that points must be cut into two labels, and only edges with different labels are cut.

Yes, these kind of cuts are usually NP-hard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut